# Is there a way to give a child element of a fixed-width div a width equal to the body element?

Tags: html, css, position, positioning

I have a fixed-width container div. I want one of the child elements to be as wide as the browser window. I would take the child element out of the parent container, but it breaks functionality. I have tried this:

```
.parent { width: 960px; position: relative; left: 50%; margin-left: -480px; }
.child { position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; }
```

on this:

```
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="other">This div's positioning is absolute but dependent on the parent element's relative positioning</div>
        <div class="child>This div wants to be centered and as wide as the browser window</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

That doesn't work though. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: The above would work if you didn't have position:relative on the parent.

Comment: I realize that, but I have another child element whose positioning is dependent upon the parent being relatively positioned.

Comment: You could have another wrapper element inside the parent and around that other child to make it relative the way it needs to be. What exactly breaks when you move the child out of the parent? It make make since to just fix the functionality and mark it up differently.

Comment: I'm with Matthew. Having a hard time understanding what could be breaking with divs outside a parent... if they are two separate divs to begin with, why does it matter how it's nested? I'll still try to help, but it seems there may be a better solution for you.

Comment: Okay, so if you look at the code, you'll notice `.parent` and `.other`. They have background images that match and I'm using JavaScript to selectively reveal `.other` when you hover over various parts of `'parent` which is why they need to line up. The div `.child` is just a nav bar that I want to be the full width of the screen, but if I take it out of `.parent` the JavaScript functionality breaks where `.child` is covering.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish exactly? using `position:relative` will cause any child element using `position:absolute` to start at the upper left hand pixel of the parent element. If you remove that, any `position:absolute` element inside the `.parent` div will go back to starting at the upper left hand pixel of the `body` instead.

Assuming you are using the relative positioning of the `.parent` div for *placement* sake and not child-element positioning (which is how it *should* be used) you can accopmlish the same thing like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">stuff</div>
    </div>
</body>

body { text-align: center; }
.parent { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;}
.child { position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; }
```

jsfiddle with size and color attributes to help illustrate the contents here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ncy5Y/

Comment: I have a relative positioned parent div because I need a different child element that is absolutely positioned to line up with the parent div. And then I have the other child div that I would like to have expand to the width of the window.

Comment: You can't do both. You will need to have one outside of the other. Theoretically you could add another container, so there could be `parent1` (no position) containing `child1` (absolutely positioned) and `child2` (relatively positioned) containing `child-child1` (absolutely positioned) inside of that one. Make sense?

Comment: So...
`<body>
    <div class="parent1">
        <div class="child1">absolute</div>
        <div class="child2">relative
            <div class="child-child1">absolute</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the current CSS configuration you should try doing this using JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.child').width($(window).width());
});
```

EDIT:

This should work and also respond to window width:

```
$(function() {
    $('.child').width($(window).width());
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.child').width($(window).width());
    });
});
```

You can create a function that contains the line that repeats if you want.

EDIT 2:

To align the element to the left use this:

```
$(function() {
    position();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        position();
    });
})

function position() {
    $('.child').width($(window).width()).offset({left: 0, top: 0});
}
```

Comment: This almost works. The width of the child div doesn't respond to changes in the window width though.

Comment: Okay, we're definitely getting somewhere. It's the correct width now but it doesn't align to the left side of the window. Can you fix that also?

Comment: I don't know why, but that just makes it act like there is not any JavaScript. It aligns to the parent div and takes the parent div's width.

Answer (score 0):

Setting size of a block relative to an arbitrary container/ancestor (not necessarily direct parent) is one of demanded features that CSS does not support unfortunately. Typical solution using existing CSS features is to divide full page to multiple horizontal lines with their own centered child elements.

For example, in the following example, second block has 100% width while first and third ones have limited width and are centered:

```html
<div class="line" id="first"><div>First line (centered)</div></div>
<div class="line" id="second">Second line (100% width)</div>
<div class="line" id="third"><div>Third line (centered)</div></div>
```

```css
.line > DIV {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

#first > DIV {background: #f00; }
#second      {background: #0f0; }
#third > DIV {background: #00f; }
```

See [**live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2fSZX/).

Comment: So... is it impossible to do what I was trying to do?

Comment: Literally, yes, it's impossible: currently, CSS allows to set width of a block relative to its direct parent element only. But in most cases you can achieve similar visual effect by using multiple independent "lines" as I've described in my answer.

Comment: So how would I do what I'm trying to do with lines? I'm a little confused.

Comment: I've slightly updated example in my answer. Now, second block has 100% width while first and third ones are centered.

Comment: Okay, and so you can use absolute and relative positioning to make them overlap and all would be right in the world?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you talking about. Isn't my example clear enough for you?